# how to get user input and store in a player object or array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simplified version of monopoly, i would like the user to be prompted with a question like - Enter player One's name, and when they do i would like the user input to be stored in a players array or object. Then i would like the user to be prompted for player Two's name, and stored in the same way.

currently my message defaults to player Two name and the user input is undefined. Any and all advice welcome.

```
function getUserInput() {
    document.getElementById('user-input').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            let input = document.getElementById('user-input').value;
            event.currentTarget.value = "";
            console.log(input);
            return input;


        }
    });
}

let message = document.getElementById('game-message');
function setPlayers() {
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player One?</p>`;
    let player1 = getUserInput();
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player Two</p>`;
    let player2 = getUserInput();
    console.log(player1, player2);
}
setPlayers();
```

Comment: whats the point of this line here? `event.currentTarget.value = "";` and also you are overwriting the HTML in message `message.innerHTML = <p>Name of player Two</p>;` so it will only show `<p>Name of player Two</p>`

Comment: it sets the input box to empty after user inputs. Any idea how to have the messages displayed according to game state. As in display this message then when input received display this message?

Comment: Honestly, there's a variety of things wrong here.  You're writing the message "Name of player X" to *the same element*, so of course the second one will over-write the first.  You're returning a value from an event handler, which doesn't do anything.  You're trying to get an entire value on the `keydown` event, so at best you can only get the *first letter* that was typed.  Now might be a good time to take a step back and start with something simpler.  Start with a single input and reading a value from that input, before moving on to creating multiple sequential inputs.

Comment: yeah i think your right i feel out of my depth with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `getUserInput` does not actually return anything.
Here your return statement is within the anonymous function for your event listener.

I would recommend using Promises to do what you want. They are essentially return statements that can run whenever you want, instead of *needing* to run immediately at the end of a specific function.

Change your `getUserInput` function to:

```
function getUserInput() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        document.getElementById("user-input").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.key !== "Enter") { return; } // only allow enter presses to resolve the Promise
            let input = this.value; // [this] references the input that the event listener was set to
            this.value = "";
            console.log(input);
            resolve(input); // this is the key part
        }); 
    });
}
```

And then modify your `setPlayers` function to:

```
// async allows the use of the "await" keyword
async function setPlayers() {
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player One?</p>`;
    // "await" waits until the Promise returned by [getUserInput] is resolved (when the resolve() function is called)
    let player1 = await getUserInput();
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player Two</p>`;
    let player2 = await getUserInput();
    console.log(player1, player2);

}
```